# get random sentences from a paragraph

Tags: php

Suppose i have a paragraph like below

```
This is sentence 1.This is sentence 2.This is sentence 3.This is sentence 4.This is sentence 5.This is sentence 6.
```

I need to get random 3 sentence from above paragraph.which results something like below

```
This is sentence 5.This is sentence 1.This is sentence 3.
```

i know its possible with explode.Is there any easy way to do it ?

```
$game = explode($string, ".")
shuffle($game);
```

Comment: Hah! Your solution is pretty easy and clear. Please, contunue to use it

Comment: @Max: but what is the point of shuffling whole array if she needs only three elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got wrong parameter order in `explode` - it's `explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )`. You should use it like this:

```
$game = explode('.', $string);
```

You will get an array with sentences. Now just print random one:

```
$id = rand(0, (count($game)-1));
echo $game[$id] . '. '; //mind adding removed dot and a space after it!
```

If you need three sentences you can simply run it in a loop. Remember about generating new `$id` each iteration!